# SQL query show customers who bought apples, but not potatoes

Tags: sql

Not sure how to explain this..

I have a similar table, but i have simplified it with the following:

I have a table of goods shipped to different cusotmers. Some have bought apples only, others have bought apples and potates.

I want an SQL query to return only customers where "To be billed" = Yes AND the customer hasnt bought any vegetables.

So for example if the table looks like this:

| Item | Name | Group | To_be_billed | CustomerNo. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Apple | Fruit | Yes | 1 |
| 2000 | Apple | Fruit | No | 2 |
| 2000 | Apple | Fruit | No | 3 |
| 2000 | Apple | Fruit | Yes | 4 |
| 2000 | Apple | Fruit | Yes | 5 |
| 4000 | Potato | Vegetable | No | 2 |
| 4000 | Potato | Vegetable | No | 4 |

I want the query to return:

| Item | Name | Group | To_be_billed | CustomerNo. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Apple | Fruit | Yes | 1 |
| 2000 | Apple | Fruit | Yes | 5 |

The reason 4 has bought apples, and is to be billed, but the customer also bought Potatoes, so is to be ignored...

Comment: What about someone who has bought apples and oranges? Should that user be returned? Apple rows only, or orange rows also?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: thank you for quick respons. the table was simplified as it has many many different items. but specifically i want to check all customers who only has bought fruits and are yet to be billed. if the customer has an item of vegetable as well then dont show these.

Comment: not sure what kind of SQL it is. The database runs on MS SQL Server, but the query is on a specific query windows within the front end system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a CTE to check for `CustomerNo.`s that you need to ignore, and then use `not exists`:

```
with bought_veg as
(
    select "CustomerNo."
    from tbl
    where tbl."Group" like 'Vegetable'
)
select tbl.*
from tbl
where not exists (select 1 from bought_veg where tbl."CustomerNo." = bought_veg."CustomerNo.")
    and tbl.To_be_billed = 'Yes'
```

Example without CTE:

```
select tbl.*
from tbl
where not exists (select "CustomerNo." from tbl t2 where tbl.[CustomerNo.] = t2.[CustomerNo.] and "Group" like 'Vegetable')
    and tbl.To_be_billed = 'Yes'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query will raise a syntax error on most dbms's.)

Comment: Thanks. i am trying to run this query in the Report generator in the frontend system, and it gives error: "Query must begin with Select" :(

Comment: Thank you, that solved it :). i am sorry, i dont have more than 15 reputaions, and cant give a +1 on the answer.